# How to perfectly blend together two images?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, images, gradient, mask

[image]

I have two mosaic images that I wish to blend together, one in blue and one in magenta. [\1]

The first approach is to add a mask of gradient opacity onto one of them, and then simply put the gradient one onto the other. [2]

However, the result didn't seem to be balanced. The one with the mask always ends up to be less than half of the total image. i.e., if the magenta one is applied with the mask, then the final result has only about 30% magenta and 70% blue, and vice versa. [3]

Is there a way to make these two images blend "perfectly", with two colors being balanced, like how a color gradient would look on a shape? [4]

Thank you!

Comment: You *could* take 4, and then [apply 1 as a `Luminosity` overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GOof.png).. but I'm not sure this is what you're after.

Comment: what do your gradients color stops look like? Remember even a transparent pixel has a color! if you do this naively you do the color change 2 times once in transparency and once in color... then we have the whole can of worms of color not being linear.

Comment: The bottom color is still 100% so your overlay (masked) color is being overpowered. You could try to mask both of the 2 colors. The blue 100% on the left to 0% on the right and the magenta from 0% on the left to 100% on the right.

Comment: I just noticed this is tagged with **Illustrator**. Yet the sample image is *clearly* a raster image. Are you working with raster images or vector objects??

Comment: @Scott It is a raster image with 16*16 pixels (a minecraft texture), so I think it would work similarly in illustrator? Also, I tried Luminosity, but it seems that the "brightness" would depend on which base image (blue or magenta) being used. I can't seem to get the "brightness" blended together as well.

Comment: @Kyle Yes it's true. But if I mask both of 2 colors, the center part would not be 100% opacity, and the background color wouls show up.

Comment: Greyscale 1 first, then apply as luminosity.. tweak levels in greyscale if needed.